# Replace immutable resource in REST API

Tags: rest, api, crud

I have a REST API which allows creation and update of some resource, let's say cars.

```
POST /cars
POST /cars/:id
```

A car has among others an `ID` field which is generated on creation by the server.

I would like to allow some business processes that use these cars to see each "revision" of a car as immutable but allow changes to the cars over the REST API so that a new "revision" is created. These revisions are on a timeline and depending on when a change is made a business process will either use it or not.

I would like to hear some thoughts on this and how to go about it.

A somewhat hacky solution is of course to just keep the cars immutable and the ID is the "revision" handle so to say. An update results in a new car with a different ID. Of course somewhat strange to call an API with an ID and get back another ID.

Thoughts and suggestions? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

OK, after looking at the suggestion to look into revisions and how StackExchange uses those for revisions across questions and answers I wonder how to practically deal with `cars` and `revisions` in terms of which object has which fields and how to find e.g. the latest version of a specific car identified by `ID`.

For instance, a car has:

```
car:
  id: 1
  brand: Toyota
  model: Yaris
  price: 1000
```

Let's say the price can change over time and this should be captured by a revision of the car, e.g.:

```
revision:
  car_id: 1
  revision: 1
  price: 900
```

Let's say I would like to get the latest car with ID 1 and it should give me that Toyota Yaris that now costs 900 instead of 1000. Are those the expected values now in the database, i.e. two rows and the latest revision (if found) overrides the other? How does this work?

**UPDATE2**

OK, so the revisions is just to keep track of the history and the latest information is in the `cars` entry itself. I.e. when an update occurs, a new revision is created with the previous values in addition to updating the cars entry. Both done in a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you handle it in a similar way as the Stack Exchange API?

```
GET /posts/{ids}/revisions
```

There's also an endpoint just for retrieving revisions:

```
GET /revisions/{ids}
```

Documentation:

- [Usage of `/posts/{ids}/revisions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids)
- [Usage of `/revisions/{ids}`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-guids)
- [Type `revision`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision)

---

Besides a *static mapping* such as `/revisions/1` or `/revisions/2`, your API could provide a URI that points to the current/latest revision, such as  `/revisions/current` or `/revisions/latest`.

A resource can have a [*mapping whose value changes over time*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and it's the case of the identifier for the current/latest revision.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to describe the process and how revisions are used to find the most up to date question and answers when showing e.g. this page?

Comment: @murrekatt For convenience, your API could provide a URI that points to the latest revision: `/cars/{ids}/revisions/latest`.

Comment: Yes it should return the latest, however, it am wondering how this is done as the latest is a "revision" and not a post and how this is pieced together nicely. Would you know?

Comment: @murrekatt I don't understand what you mean. Implementation concerns go beyond the scope of this answer. But keep in mind that a resource can have a [_mapping whose value changes over time_](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and it's the case of the identifier for the _latest_ revision.

Comment: Basically, looking at a `post`, how does one determine e.g. the `title` as this is in both the `post` as well as in the `revision`. Is it simply: "give me post p and then check in revisions by `post_id` and grab the highest `revision` and then populate the post with values in the revision"? I.e. from where does the `post` field values come from if there are N revisions? The post, all revisions or last revision or a combination? :)

Comment: updated by question to clarify what I am wondering, i.e. how those mappings work in practice. Any good suggestion?

Comment: @murrekatt The most updated information of your resource will be in the resource itself (for example `/cars/1`). If you need a "log" of changes, check the revisions (for example `/cars/1/revisions`).